# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:zipalignDebug' when big folder in assets

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem with building app with big folder in assets. My folder size is equal 179 MB and size on disk is 463mb, because it contains huge amount of small files. When I remove one subfolder, which size is 90% of whole content, everything build successfully. When I zip whole folder everything works as well. The problem is when I have whole content unzipped in assets.

This is my build.gradle script for app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```

and logs

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubNirhartParallaxscroll10Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIleo_branchingBLB_SDKUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIleo_branchingOsmbonuspack_v561UnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
Unable to open 'C:\Users\directory to app\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk' as zip archive
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:zipalignDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\xxx\Android\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5 mins 21.971 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I'm using android studio 2.1.1, the gradle tools version 2.1.0

Have you got any idea how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply **Build > Clean Project** solved my problem.

Comment: Tried but not helped me.